# Persist additional claims details from external provider

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

We are trying external login (Identityserver4) in .NET Core and we have used external provider i.e. Google. we are able to retrieve data such as first name, last name, email, etc of a google user's during logged in. But we are not able to retrieve the user's telephone number and other additional claims.

`Startup.Auth.cs` :

```
            services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle("Google", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.ClientId = "XXX";
            options.ClientSecret = "XXX";
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.OtherPhone, "otherphone");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:picture", "picture", "url");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:locale", "locale", "string");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:MobilePhone", "mobilephone", "string");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:gender", "gender", "string");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:birthday", "birthday", "date");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:accesstoken", "AccessToken", "string");
            options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Gender, "gender");
            options.SaveTokens = true;

        });
```

We have added `options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:MobilePhone", "mobilephone", "string");` this line but we are not getting mobile number. The same line of code is work for the picture but for a mobile number is not working.

Comment: if you want to get user phone numbers you have to have authorization from the user: see the following info page : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing

Comment: Thanks! Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

we have tried using google API authorization and get the below information:

```
{
  "id": "xxx",
  "email": "xx@gmail.com",
  "verified_email": true,
  "name": "PoojaParmar",
  "given_name": "Pooja",
  "family_name": "Parmar",
  "picture": "/photo.jpg",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

But we need the logged in google user's mobile number. Below is the line of code which we have configured in our action methods:

```
var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
                var claims = result.Principal.Claims.ToList();
                string accessToken = result.Properties.Items[".Token.access_token"];
                var web = new WebClient
                {
                    Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                };
                try
                {
                    var response = web.DownloadString("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accessToken + "&scope=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"));
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    //return;
                }
```